# slider doesnt work in IE8

Tags: jquery, html, css, anythingslider

Im using AnythingSlider for my slider - However, in IE8 it doesnt slide between the 3 slides i've got, cant quite figure out why ? [The site is here](http://cinemaxx.dk/aarhus/)

Comment: You will find out that lot's of stuff is not working with IE :) Did you check in AnythingSlider Website that it supports IE8 ?

Comment: It should be compatible with IE8

Comment: There are 183 validation errors. Have you tried making the slider work with clean HTML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're missing the latest changes to the css file that were added with the fade mode option ([ref](https://github.com/CSS-Tricks/AnythingSlider/blob/master/css/anythingslider.css#L256-L267))

```
/* fade mode */
.anythingSlider .fade .panel {
    float: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 0;
}
/* fade mode active page - visible & on top */
.anythingSlider .fade .activePage {
    z-index: 1;
}
```